# Easy to use strongly-typed JSON library for C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, oop, list

I need an easy-to-setup JSON library for C# .NET that can work well with strongly-typed Lists and Dictionaries. I've been working with [fastJSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON), which is lightweight and portable. However the methods `ToJSON` and `ToObject` do not always work with strongly typed objects such as `List<string>`.  I need a simple library that can execute the following correctly:

```
// parse a JSON file
List<string> names = JSON.parse<List<string>>(json1);
Dictionary<string, int> ids = JSON.parse<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);

// stringify an object
string json = JSON.stringify(names);
string json = JSON.stringify(ids);
```

Obviously the ideal library should be fast (fast enough to scale to JSONs that are hundreds of MBs), and portable (small code, no dependencies), but no fusses. I'm pretty desperate right now so anything that works is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx is the usual answer but there are many more.

```
        List<string> names = new List<string>() {"Mike","Joe","Jane"};
        Dictionary<string, int> ids = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                                          {
                                              {"Mike",1},
                                              {"Joe",2},
                                              {"Jane",3},
                                          };

        // ["Mike","Joe","Jane"]
        string nameJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(names);

        //{"Mike":1,"Joe":2,"Jane":3}
        string idsJSon = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ids);
```

Comment: What do you mean by parse it? Do you mean converting the JSON into an object?

Comment: Parsing means converting a JSON string into a runtime class object.

Answer (score 2):

Check ServiceStack.Text: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

I have used it in couple of projects and its pretty good.

From the wiki page:

> ServiceStack.Text is an independent, dependency-free serialization
>   library that contains all of ServiceStack's text processing
>   functionality, including:
>
> ```
> JsonSerializer
> TypeSerializer (JSV-Format)
> CsvSerializer
> T.Dump extension method
> StringExtensions - Xml/Json/Csv/Url encoding, BaseConvert, Rot13, Hex escape, etc.
> Stream, Reflection, List, DateTime, etc extensions and utils
> ```